# i have an issue getting my footer to take the whole width of the page

Tags: android, xml

I have an android app with a small toolbar at the bottom acting like a footer. I am having an issue where the footer is not taking the full width of the screen. I know it's a small issue with the layouts but i can't seem to find the exact issue.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".app.LoginActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/toolBar">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/loginbannerimage"
                android:contentDescription="banner"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/icons_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <!-- Login progress -->
                <include layout="@layout/custom_progress_bar"/>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:cardElevation="3dp"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/toolBar"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:text="Welcome To MAP"
                                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                                    android:textSize="20sp"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:padding="5dp"
                                    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardBg"
                                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
                                android:padding="5dp">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:orientation="vertical"
                                    android:padding="15dp">
                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/email"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="Email here"
                                        android:maxLines="1"
                                        android:singleLine="true" />

                                    <EditText
                                        android:id="@+id/password"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:hint="Password"
                                        android:imeActionLabel="Password here"
                                        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                                        android:inputType="textPassword"
                                        android:maxLines="1"
                                        android:singleLine="true" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                                        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                                        android:text="Sign-in"
                                        android:textStyle="bold"
                                        android:elevation="5dp"
                                        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>


                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/footer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <include layout="@layout/footer">

            </include>

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

It comes out showing like this 
[image]

Below is footer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/address_1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:padding="3dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/address_2"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/address_3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="3dp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/black"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/contact_1"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:padding="3dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/contact_2"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="3dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/contact_3"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
                    android:textSize="8sp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:padding="3dp"/>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/grey_500"
                app:cardCornerRadius="0dp">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:src="@drawable/mapfootericon"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:text="@string/copyright"
                            android:textSize="11sp"
                            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                            android:paddingTop="8dp"/>

                    </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: show `layout/footer.xml`

Comment: Yes, footer is the problem. When I removed it, it looks fine.

Comment: @Lev i need the footer to show

Comment: Ahh it's the Toolbar. Remove it. Toolbars have an icon to the left by default, I think it's invisible and making a mess. You don't need the toolbar anyways, just remove it and add th's

<include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                layout="@layout/footer"></include>

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

change `wrap_content` to `match_parent`